# How to draw these vectors in Latex?

Tags: tikz-arrows

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/svq2N.png]

How do I make this drawing in latex?

Comment: Is there a precise angle that you want to have your image?

Comment: what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
                    scale=0.5,
                    line cap=round,
                    ]

\path (0,0) coordinate[label=left:{O}] (O) 
          (3,2) node[label=right:{V}](A){} 
          (6,-4) node[label=right:{W}](B){} 
(O) edge[thick,->] (A) edge[thick,->] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to draw with  `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, semithick]
\draw[<->]  (1, 1) coordinate[label=right:V] (V) --
            (0, 0) coordinate[label= left:O] (O) --
            (3,-2) coordinate[label=right:W] (W);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice border! :)